# Verify login data from username and password columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, authentication

I wrote the following function to verify log in data for user, but so far its not working as it should and I am sure there is something wrong with it:

```
Private Sub button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles button2.Click
    If loginpasswordtx.Text.Length > 1 And loginpasswordtx.Text.Length > 1 And My.Settings.SQLConnectionString.Length > 5 Then
        Try
            Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.SQLConnectionString)
            Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT AppUser,AppUserPass FROM OrderAppUsers WHERE AppUser=@AppUser AND AppUserPass=@AppUserPass", cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AppUser", createuserAppUser.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AppUserPass", MD5StringHash(loginpasswordtx.Text)))
            cnn.Open()

            Dim obj As Object = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            If obj = Nothing Then
                MsgBox("Faild to Log in, check your log in info")
                cnn.Close()
                Return
            End If
            cnn.Close()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Return
        End Try

        MsgBox("Logged in Successfully")
    End If
End Sub
```

All I get is a `null obj` even though user and pass exist in the table.

the following code is for adding new users

```
 Try
            Dim cnnstring As String = String.Format("Server={0};Database={1};Trusted_Connection=True;", createuserServerTx.Text, createuserDatabaseTx.Text)
            Dim cnn As New SqlConnection(cnnstring)
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO OrderAppUsers VALUES (@AppUser, @AppUserPass)", cnn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AppUser", createuserAppUser.Text))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@AppUserPass", MD5StringHash(createuserpassword.Text)))
            cnn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cnn.Close()
            MsgBox("User Crated Successfully")
            LayoutControl1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
            My.Settings.SQLConnectionString = cnnstring
            My.Settings.Save()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

and the function to generate a custom hash

```
 Private Function MD5StringHash(ByVal strString As String) As String
    Dim MD5 As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim Data As Byte()
    Dim Result As Byte()
    Dim R As String = ""
    Dim Temp As String = ""

    Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strString)
    Result = MD5.ComputeHash(Data)
    For i As Integer = 0 To Result.Length - 1
        Temp = Hex(3 * Result(i) + 1)
        If Len(Temp) = 1 Then Temp = "0" & Temp
        R += Temp
    Next
    Return R
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following when adding parameter

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppUser", createuserAppUser.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppUserPass", MD5StringHash(loginpasswordtx.Text))
```

or just stick with what you did but a little different than yours,

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppUser", SqlDbType.VarChar)       
cmd.Parameters("@AppUser").Value = createuserAppUser.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppUserPass", SqlDbType.VarChar)       
cmd.Parameters("@AppUserPass").Value = MD5StringHash(loginpasswordtx.Text)
```

by the way, when using `ExecuteScalar()` it only returns single value. So your query can be written as

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM OrderAppUsers
WHERE AppUser=@AppUser AND AppUserPass=@AppUserPass
```

and you can use `int` variable to store its value

```
Dim obj As int = Cint(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
```

so the possible values are `0` or the total number of records return.

```
If obj = 0 Then
    MsgBox("Faild to Log in, check your log in info")
    '' other codes
End If
```

and by refractoring your code, use `Using -Statement`

```
Using cnn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.SQLConnectionString)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderAppUsers WHERE AppUser=@AppUser AND AppUserPass=@AppUserPass", cnn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppUser", createuserAppUser.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppUserPass", MD5StringHash(loginpasswordtx.Text))
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Try
            cnn.Open()
            Dim obj As int = Cint(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            If obj = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Faild to Log in, check your log in info")
            Else
                 MsgBox("Logged in Successfully")
            End If
        Catch(ex As SqlException)
             MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: still the same problem and i can't figure what is wrong, funny thing is it works only when i create a new user and try to log in, after i close the application and try to log in again with the same user it says ""Faild to Log in, check your log in info", i added the code of how i add a user to the databae in the question

Comment: @user1570048 did you check the database if the insert was successful?

Comment: @user1570048 actually i don't know if your adding of parameter works. it should be `cmd.Parameters.Add("@AppUser", SqlDbType.VarChar)` then to add value `cmd.Parameters("@AppUser").Value = createuserAppUser.Text` or can you try using `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppUser", createuserAppUser.Text)`

Comment: same thing, this is really annoying, i can see the users added to the database this is not the problem, it must be the something with login function!

Comment: loading the data to a datatable and the checking works, also using a reader works, but why its really strange why it doesnt work using parameters!

Comment: very weird. can you check the value of `MD5StringHash(loginpasswordtx.Text)` first before passing it in parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code in my local system and it is working fine i mean i was able to validate its return true i analysis and found its return false only when i am adding one space on password text before encrypt can u check in database value is space adding into password value or can u post your encrypt code

Comment: great, i've a added the function to generate a custom password hash to the question, can you please check it if it works with this function?